# What does this sentence mean: "You said, levelling your voice"?

Tags: meaning, sentence, sentence-meaning

What does it mean ***to level one's voice at someone***?
The full sentence is:

> You said, levelling your voice at him as if it was a sword.

Comment: Levelling a sword or spear or criticism at someone is not the same meaning as levelling a building.

Comment: From the context it's inferable that it means to raise your voice, or like @YosefBaskin has pointed in his answer, to weaponise it.
I couldn't find any written reference though, but I'm sure that's the meaning of it.

Comment: Either you've left out part of the sentence or it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

To level your voice would mean to even it out. However, to *level your voice at someone* like a sword means to **weaponize** it.

Oxford's Lexico has level as [**aim a weapon**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/level):

> #3: ‘He levelled a pistol at us.’

Answer (score 0):

It is an idiomatic expression meaning speak in  a calm or determined manner:

***[level](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/level-voice-look-gaze) voice/look/gaze:***

> a steady voice, look etc that shows you are calm or determined.

(Longman Dictionary)

Comment: Using this definition, the recipient of the verbal message would have no doubt that the speaker was directing the comments to him specifically. This seems to be the most likely meaning of this phrase.